# How can I set a container as public from the v12 Azure Storage Java SDK

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to programatically create an Azure Storage container with the public read flag on blobs using Java:

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().
        endpoint(BLOB_ENDPOINT).
        sasToken(BLOB_SAS_TOKEN).
        buildClient();
String cName = "my_container_name";
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(cName);

if(!containerClient.exists()) {
    // The next line works OK
    containerClient.create();

    BlobSignedIdentifier identifier = new BlobSignedIdentifier()
            .setId("publicreadaccess")
            .setAccessPolicy(new BlobAccessPolicy()
                    .setStartsOn(OffsetDateTime.now().minusDays(1))
                    .setExpiresOn(OffsetDateTime.now().plusYears(5))
                    .setPermissions("r"));
    // Throws exception:
    containerClient.setAccessPolicy(PublicAccessType.BLOB, Collections.singletonList(identifier));
}
```

This code fails with:

> **com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobStorageException: Status code 403,
>   "﻿`AuthorizationFailure`This
>   request is not authorized to perform this operation.
>   RequestId:e5bedc3a-001e-0070-1c70-3981ba000000
>   Time:2020-06-03T06:29:42.6683502Z"
>   com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobStorageException: Status code 403,
>   "﻿`AuthorizationFailure`This
>   request is not authorized to perform this operation.
>   RequestId:e5bedc3a-001e-0070-1c70-3981ba000000
>   Time:2020-06-03T06:29:42.6683502Z"**    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   com.azure.core.http.rest.RestProxy.instantiateUnexpectedException(RestProxy.java:357)
>     at
>   com.azure.core.http.rest.RestProxy.lambda$ensureExpectedStatus$3(RestProxy.java:400)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1592)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.onNext(MonoProcessor.java:317)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1592)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1592)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.subscribe(MonoProcessor.java:383)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:55)
>     at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)    at
>   reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4087)     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.add(MonoProcessor.java:457)

I've created a SAS that is *very* allowing - but I still get this issue.
using the old SDK it works fine. I've googled for a day - but I can't find any documentation what the SAS permissions should be to make a BLOB public readable.
Changing it manually in the azure portal works fine - but we need to be able to do through code.

Comment: with SAS token you can only list all blobs. For changing the container access level you need to use the storage key based client.

Comment: @aravind do you have any example or link to documentation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Blob Storage - Changing permissions of a container and accessing with SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434864/azure-blob-storage-changing-permissions-of-a-container-and-accessing-with-sas)

Comment: @Aravind thanks for the link - but that is how it used to work, as I said creating is no problem just how to exactly change the permission. The documenation doesn't say anything about this